# why the map function of sc.cassandraTable("test", "users").select("username") can not work?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

Following [spark-cassandra-connector's demo](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md) and [Installing the Cassandra / Spark OSS Stack](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/installing-the-cassandra-spark-oss-stack/), under spark-shell, I tried the following snippet:

```
sc.stop
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "172.21.0.131")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "adminxx")
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "adminxx")
val sc = new SparkContext("172.21.0.131", "Cassandra Connector Test", conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "users").select("username")
```

Many operators of `rdd` can work fine, such as:

```
rdd.first
rdd.count
```

But when I use `map`:

```
val result = rdd.map(x => 1) //just for simple
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[61] at map at <console>:32
```

Then, I run:

```
result.first
```

I got the following errors:

```
15/12/11 15:09:00 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 104, 124.250.36.124): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

$line346.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
```

I don't know why I got such error? Any advice will be appreciated!

UPDATED:
According [@RussSpitzer](https://twitter.com/RussSpitzer)'s answer for [CassandraRdd.map( row => row.getInt("id)) does not work , java.lang.ClassNotFoundException happened!](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/spark-connector-user/BAsDx7TPS18/wIUR4xgwAAAJ), I resolved this error through following errors, instead of using `sc.stop` and creating an new `SparkContext`, I start `spark-shell` with options:

```
bin/spark-shell -conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=172.21.0.131 --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=adminxx --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=adminxx
```

And then all steps are the same and work fine.

Comment: after any change you need to rebuild your project and then run your program

Comment: It's an odd one, but you might be having a namespace clash because your RDD is called rdd, try it with another variable name maybe?

Comment: I call 90% of my RDDs `rdd`. Why would that clash with anything? You can call your variables whatever you like.

Comment: @kaushal: This is `spark-shell`, there is nothing to recompile. But I think you are right. This code would probably work when compiled. It's just an issue with `spark-shell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark applications normally send their compiled code as jar files to the executors. This way the function that you `map` is present on the executors.

The situation is more tricky in `spark-shell`. It has to compile and broadcast the code for your every line interactively. There is not even a class you're operating inside. It creates these fake `$$iwC$$` classes to solve this.

Normally this works out well, but you may have hit a `spark-shell` bug. You can try to work around it by putting your code inside a class in `spark-shell`:

```
object Obj { val mapper = { x: String => 1 } }
val result = rdd.map(Obj.mapper)
```

But it is probably safest to implement your code as an application instead of just writing it in `spark-shell`.

Comment: [@RussSpitzer](https://twitter.com/RussSpitzer) correctly answer the same question in google group [CassandraRdd.map( row => row.getInt("id)) does not work , java.lang.ClassNotFoundException happened!](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/spark-connector-user/BAsDx7TPS18/wIUR4xgwAAAJ), Of course, I am newbie for Spark, I don't know your answer exactly explains why that what I also want to know, Whether you fill up more explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! I've copied his answer to an answer here as well. Following my advice would also have helped you, since if you have an application, you are not given a SparkContext but have to create one for yourself. But that's just by luck :). His answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

[Russell Spitzer's answer from the `spark-connector-user` list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/spark-connector-user/BAsDx7TPS18/wIUR4xgwAAAJ):

> I'm pretty sure the main problem here is that you start a context with `--jars` and then kill that context and then start another one. Try simplifying your code, instead of setting all of those spark conf options and creating a new contexts run your shell like. Also the jar that you want on the classpath is the connector assembly jar, not a custom build of a Scala script you want to run.
>
> `./spark-shell --conf spark.casandra.connection.host=10.129.20.80 ...`
>
> You should not need to modify the `ack.wait.timeout` or the `executor.extraClasspath`.